# Writing seriated files with loop

Tags: r, serialization, for-loop, write.table

I am writing a function that opens all the files in dir(), does some calculation and rearrangement and then writes (write.table) each file again in dir()

```
dir()
 [1] "v2p1"  "v2p10" "v2p11" "v2p12" "v2p2"  "v2p3"  "v2p4"  "v2p5"  "v2p6"  "v2p7" 
[11] "v2p8"  "v2p9"  "v2r1"  "v2r10" "v2r11" "v2r12" "v2r2"  "v2r3"  "v2r4"  "v2r5" 
[21] "v2r6"  "v2r7"  "v2r8"  "v2r9"  "v2s1"  "v2s10" "v2s11" "v2s12" "v2s2"  "v2s3" 
[31] "v2s4"  "v2s5"  "v2s6"  "v2s7"  "v2s8"  "v2s9"
```

The code looks like this and it does the everything fine except that the loop is not working.

```
mysub <- function(x) {sub(",",".",x)}
abrir<-function(etapa){  
### volnum c(1:10) indica en qué vol quiero,
### etapa c("p","r","s") indica en qué etapa es del experimento

i<-1
for (i in dir()){

##### ABRIR ARCHIVOS DESDE DIR() ######
Archivo<-paste(getwd(),"/",i,sep="")
r1<-read.table(Archivo,fill=T,sep=",")

##### CALCULAR LA VELOCIDAD DE CADA CORRIDA ######
r11 <- (apply(r1, 2, mysub ))
r1<- data.frame(apply(r11, 2, as.numeric)) ## ojo que pueden aparecer NA
R1<-r1[1:3136,]     ### OJO, DEPENDE LA CORRIDA, SACA LOS VALORES DEL FINAL QUE NO SIRVEN
V<-data.frame(rbind(c(0,0,0,0),(abs(diff(as.matrix(R1[,2:5]))))))
Tiempo<-R1[,1]
Velocidad<-data.frame(Tiempo,V)  

##### GUARDAR LAS VELOCIDADES QUE CORRESPONDEN  ######

if (grep("p",i)==TRUE){
salida<-paste("VEL",i,".txt",sep="")
write.table(Velocidad,salida,sep="\t",row.names=FALSE)
} else if (grep("r",i)==TRUE){
salida<-paste("VEL",i,".txt",sep="")
write.table(Velocidad,salida,sep="\t",row.names=FALSE)
}else if(grep("s",i)==TRUE){
salida<-paste("VEL",i,".txt",sep="")
write.table(Velocidad,salida,sep="\t",row.names=FALSE)
}else stop("etapa inválida")
i<-i+1
}
}
```

abrir() saves me a correct "VELv2p1.txt" and returns this error
Error in i + 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

I don't know how to explain R to continue with the second element once it's done i=1 I guess i<-i+1 it's not the way. I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is related to the fact that `i` in your loop is a `character` object, not `numeric`. The syntax `for(i in dir())` yields the actual files in `i`, not the index. In using `for` like this, there is no need to set `i` to the next item, the `for` loop will take of that. So simply deleting `i <- i + 1` will solve your issue.

Some remarks regarding your code:

- Indentation will improve the readability of your code. As will adding spaces.
- You can put the call to write.table at the end of the function, saving you three identical lines of code. Actually, the set of `if` statements all seem to execute the same code.
- `for` loops are generally not the best option in R. Vectorized or `apply` based solution yield shorter, and sometimes faster code.

I'd roughly take the following approach:

```
list_of_files = list.files('.')
do_some_calculations = function(file, output_name) {
    output_name = sprintf('VEL%d.txt', list_of_files)
    Archivo<-paste(getwd(), "/", i, sep = "")
    r1<-read.table(Archivo,fill = T, sep = ",")
    r11 <- (apply(r1, 2, mysub ))
    r1<- data.frame(apply(r11, 2, as.numeric)) ## ojo que pueden aparecer NA
    R1<-r1[1:3136,]     ### OJO, DEPENDE LA CORRIDA, SACA LOS VALORES DEL FINAL QUE NO SIRVEN
    V <- data.frame(rbind(c(0,0,0,0), (abs(diff(as.matrix(R1[,2:5]))))))
    Tiempo <- R1[,1]
    Velocidad <- data.frame(Tiempo, V)  
    write.table(Velocidad, output_name,s ep="\t", row.names=FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I understood what you ment. I don't like the for loops neither but i thought it was the only way. Now the loop goes trhough the whole v2pi and stops returning this error Error in if (grep("p", i) == TRUE) { : argument is of length zero. I used grep because its matches trhough a character such as my i

Comment: Forget it, I depleted the if statements and worked fine, thank you!!